# For expert i need to create a new db using sql in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I took 4 days searching for a new database creation using SQL in java. I found that I can do it by using the following code but I don't get what I want.

As far as I can tell the database is not created. How can I find out if the database is created?

My code is

```
 public class DataManaging {

    private Connection Connecter;

    private Statement Stat;

    private ResultSet Result;

    private String pass,user;

    public DataManaging(){
        user = "root";
        pass = "root";
      try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            try {
                  Connecter = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306", user, pass);
                  Stat = Connecter.createStatement();
                  Stat.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS FATEH;");

                  Stat.executeUpdate("USE FATEH");
                  Stat.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ROOMS(N INT auto_increment PRIMARY key,Floor INT NOT NULL,Class VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,Situation VARCHAR(10),Reservation_Date DATE,Duration INT,Reserver_Name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL)");


              } catch (SQLException e) {
                  System.out.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
                  System.out.println("SQLState: " + e.getSQLState());
                  System.out.println("VendorError: " + e.getErrorCode());
              }
      }catch (Exception ex) {
          System.out.println(ex);
      }
    }
}
}
```

After run the code I get

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Looks like you need to _run_ the code. Are you using ant or maven? You need to call `java -jar myCompiledCode.jar`.

Comment: @drewmore I think the OP is building the code. It needs to be executed.

Comment: i use NetBeans 7.2.1 i have executed the code using my main project class but i need the results as the data base wich named <FATEH>

Comment: Have you logged into your mysql database and checked whether it exists?

Comment: i told that i can't find it in any place it won't be created even when i run the code thousends of time and every time i get
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds) but nothing happen

Comment: and i try to use any query it return empty results

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-create-database.htm

I am not sure you can use `use <databasename>` with JDBC

Maybe you should close the connection and try connecting to the new database using  this URL

`jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/databaseName`

Comment: It'd probably be better to simply use qualified names than creating a new connection.